# with which intel processor do you compare AMD A8-7410 Quad Core?

Tags: cpu, intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5

I never had a laptop with AMD processor. I found a very good laptop with AMD A8-7410 Quad Core 4x2.40 GHz processor. 
I'm not into gaming or video processing, but i do use photoshop, illustrator and phpstorm(Projects sizes are sometimes big).
With which Intel processor do you compare this processor(AMD A8-7410)? Will it be able to handle my tasks?
Do AMD processors have good quality?

Comment: The title and body have conflict model number.

Comment: corrected the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A comparable CPU to the A8-7410 would be the Intel Core i5 7200u. The A6-7310 is probably closer to older versions of the low-TDP i5 lineup. Those particular processors, if you're using the integrated graphics, might struggle a bit with the workload, though I have not worked with them. AMD and Intel processors have little disparity in terms of quality, from what I've heard.

Answer (score 0):

https://cpubenchmark.net/cpu.php?cpu=AMD+A8-7410+APU

You can compare it with other CPUs.

https://www.cpubenchmark.net/CPU_mega_page.html